# jqGrid after Delete error

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jqgrid

Here is the example delete options I'm using using in a jqGrid.  It works just fine and my serverside scripts are working perfectly.  The records get deleted, but there is something that goes wrong after the response from the server is received.

```
// Del Options
{
    mtype: "POST",
    modal: true,
    url: "/internal/backupmanagement/backupmanager/deleteMySQLDB",
    reloadAfterSubmit: false,
    onclickSubmit: function () {
        var post = $("#grid_" + o.id).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
        var server = post.serverID;
        $.openDialog("load", "Deleting old database entry.  Please wait...");
        var selrow = $("#grid_" + o.id).jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
        var row = $("#grid_" + o.id).jqGrid("getRowData", selrow);
        console.log("about to return", row, server);
        return {
            id: row.recid,
            database: row.database,
            server: server
        };
    },
    afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
        response = eval("(" + response.responseText + ")");
        console.log(response);
        return [true, "success"];
    },
    afterComplete: function (response, postdata, formid) {
        response = eval("(" + response.responseText + ")");
        var selrow = $("#grid_" + o.id).jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
        $("#grid_" + o.id).jqGrid("delRowData", selrow);
        if (response.error == 0) {
            $.openDialog("info", "Successfully deleted " + postdata.database + ".");
        } else {
            $.openDialog("info", "And error occured - " + response.msg + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error before the afterComplete event is fired in the grid :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'split'
```

So it seems something is being returned as an object when it was expecting a string.  I'm not sure if my response from the server is formatted correctly and I wasn't able to find any expected response in the documentation either.

*** UPDATE ***
Server-side code as requested.  I've just included the controller function that interacts with the jqGrid, the rest is working and happening further on in the application.

```
function deleteMySQLDB()
{
  if (IS_AJAX) {
    if (($this->Application->deleteMySQLDBData(
        $_POST["id"],
        $_POST["database"],
        $_POST["server"]
    )) === false) {
      echo json_encode(
          array(
            "error" => 1,
            "msg"   => "Failed Deleting record from database: "
                       .$this->Application->error
          )
      );
      return false;
    }
    echo json_encode(
        array(
          "error" => 0,
          "msg"   => "success"
        )
    );
    return true;
  } else {
    header("Location: /");
  }
}
```

I hope this helps to see what I'm currently returning to the grid.

*** UPDATE ***
What I have done is changed the source in the jqGrid plugin to include a toString() on the value before preforming the split.

On line 331 of jquery.jqGrid.min.4.3.1 :

var A=[];A=H.split(",");

Changed to :

var A=[];A=H.toString().split(",");

It seemed like a harmless change in the grand scheme of things and avoids arrays to be attempted to get split.  Thanks a lot for the help guys.  You certainly pointed me in the right place to start looking, Oleg!

Comment: Not that it will fix your problem, but instead of `response = eval("(" + response.responseText + ")");` (if you're expecting an object literal), try `response = JSON.parse(response.responseText);`. Or even `$.parseJSON()`. But it depends on what you expect back in the response

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian, I have done so, I haven't come across that jQuery functionality yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose that the origin of the described error is the code of your `afterComplete` callback. I think that you are using it in a wrong way. I don't understand some parts of the code, the part (testing of `response.error`) should be moved in `afterSubmit`.

The main problem will be clear if you examine [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.formedit.js#L1674-L1676) of code where `afterComplete` callback will be called. It will be executed inside of `setTimeout` with 0.5 sec delay. At the time new data in the grid can be loaded (or could be loading). So it would be wrong to use methods like `delRowData` and the value of `selrow` could be changed now.

I would strictly recommend you additionally don't use `eval` function. Instead of the line

```
response = eval("(" + response.responseText + ")");
```

it will be correct to use

```
response = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
```

The code of `onclickSubmit` callback could be improved if you would use the fact that `this` inside of the callback (like the most other callbacks o jqGrid) are initialized to DOM element of the grid. So to get `selrow` option of the grid you can use

```
var selrow = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
```

instead of

```
var selrow = $("#grid_" + o.id).jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
```

Another fact is `onclickSubmit` will be called by jqGrid with two parameters: `options` and `postdata`. The parameter `postdata` is rowid if you use don't use `multiselect: true`. In case of usage of `multiselect: true` the value of `postdata` parameter of the callback can be comma separated list of rowids of the rows which will be deleted. So the usage of `postdata` is better as the usage of `selrow`.

Comment: Thanks a whole lot for the response Oleg.  I have made the changes to the code where you recommended, except for the use of "this" for the selrow, as jqGrid is being used here in a widget context.

Comment: Also, I have used console logs on the first line inside of the afterComplete callback and code execution never reaches it at all.  So the error is encountered somewhere after the afterSubmit callback and before the afterComplete one.

Thanks all the same!

Comment: @Lemon: I'm not PHP developer, but using [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)or [http_response_code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) you can return error from the server. In the case `errorTextFormat` callback instead of `afterSubmit` will be executed. It's the standard way how jqGrid process error. Independent from "widget context" `this` will be the DOM of grid in the callbacks like `afterComplete`. So you don't need **search** for element by id with `$("#grid_" + o.id)`, you can just get it with `$(this)`.

Comment: @Lemon: Is your main problem (error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'split'") solved now? If not yet, that you should use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and post **the line number** in `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` where you get the error.

Comment: I have managed to get my way to the place in the minimised code where the split happens.  (Line 331 of the minimised version of the plugin.)  It seems the single row ID that is being passed is in an array at the time of the split being executed on it.  I don't understand why jqGrid is converting the ID that has been passed to it as a string to an array and then performing a split on it.

Comment: @Lemon: I remind me that it was such error in some old version of jqGrid. You don't mention in your question **which version of jqGrid you use**. In the case it should be the last one (4.4.5). Which version you used really? Could you repeat the test with `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`? One line of mininized version corresponds 100 lines of original code so Line 331 get no information. If some bug exist in jqGrid it's important to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm currently using 4.3.1 on this project.  I know it's an older release and it is the very last project I'll be using this version of the plugin on.  Moving to 4.4.5 on the next one! ;)

Comment: Yeah you were right on the money Oleg! It was the older version having the trouble.  I applied the fix I mentioned in the last update and it fixed the trouble.  You have my deepest thanks, this trouble had me stuck for the better part of yesterday and this morning, hehe!

Comment: @Lemon: You are welcome! Now everything is clear. The problem which you described is fixed many time before (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/5ab94c7e8bf9e1f5df29923ce4384d71ef357469) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/bug-with-delgridrow-object-being-treated-as-a-string/)). If I remind correctly the bug exist only in version 4.3.1 (not in versions <=4.3.0 and not in versions >4.3.2). If you use not the last version of jqGrid then please write about that always in your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

I"m making a good guess since you didn't include your server side code.

On the server you can return something like:

```
return Json(new { success = false, showMessage = true, message = "Error - You can't have a negative value", title = "Error" });
```

Then on your client you can have something to display a message (in this example if there was an error)

```
afterComplete: function (response) {
                        var DialogVars = $.parseJSON(response.responseText); //parse the string that was returned in responseText into an object

                        if (!DialogVars.success || DialogVars.showMessage) {
                            showDialog($('#Dialog'), DialogVars.message, DialogVars.title);
                        }
                    } //afterComplete
```

Comment: I have added Server scripts to help you diagnose the trouble.  This is what I was looking for as I suspected that it had to do with the server response somehow being in the incorrect format.  Though I'm not sure.